# Circle with shadow CSS 3

Tags: css, radial-gradients

At my web page I have `background: gray`, and now I need to add a white shadow circle such as shown in the picture. One of my decisions is to add `url:('../img/background.png') no-repeat gray` but I can't connect the colors because the image had a vertical gradient.

I think that it is possible to do this using CSS 3, am I right?

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's radial gradient.

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(circle, #fff, #b1b5be 150px);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #fff, #b1b5be 150px);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #fff, #b1b5be 150px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Live demo: [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/OCz6fTwa)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also create white circle shadow by blurring div with white circle  image through css filters.

Webkit:
`-webkit-filter: blur(15px);`

IE: `filter: blur(Add=1, Direction=1, Strength=15)`

In Firefox by using SVG filter through CSS